# Changing download folder for a specific web application

Tags: javascript, browser

I think the answer is going to be "not possible" but it doesn't hurt to ask.

I've created a web application for a specific user that in part creates Word Doc documents on the server that they then download to their local machines.

My end user is not an experienced computer user and occasionally "loses" the files they've downloaded.  (They're in the default download directory mixed in with other things they've downloaded!).  It would be preferred if files downloaded from my web application went to a specific folder.

Is there a way to do this either in the web apps code or as a configuration of their browser?

The web app is built using MS Web API 2/C# for the server and Javascript/JQuery/Knockout on the client side.

Comment: If they're willing to install plugin on their browser , it's possible! but you have to write a plugin (Add-On or whatever you may call it)!

Comment: It depends on the size of your .doc(s), but if you're willing to be HTML5, you could store them into LocalStorage (WebSQL/IndexedDB). Then check if there's something already in it.

Comment: It's very difficult to combat user ignorance. One solution would be to open the word document in a new tab, rather than directly downloading it. that way they will have the document "just there" and they can save it where they like.